# How to Verify reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement reCAPTCHA on a contact form & I'm stuck. The function is showing up on my page (that was easy) but now I'm confused as to how to verify the CAPTCHA. I have a "send-mail.php" file that verify's the input data & then sends it to a specified email address. Should I somehow include the reCAPTCHA verification within this file? If so, how do I do so?

**[Link to contact form](http://tinyurl.com/cm3zzuw)**

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: usually the recapcha library should have a way to check it. RTFM

Comment: Have you tried to read reCAPTCHA documentation?

Comment: Yes I read through it & I'm stuck.

Comment: What have you got so far?  https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

Comment: I read through this: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

and this is where I'm lost.

Comment: I should clarify that I don't know PHP

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the "official" PHP plugin (http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/), this is what I used to use:

```
<?php
    # Get a key from http://recaptcha.net/api/getkey
    $publickey = "";
    $privatekey = "";

    @require_once( 'path/to/recaptchalib.php' );

    # the response from reCAPTCHA
    $resp = null;

    # was there a reCAPTCHA response?
    if( $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"] ) 
    {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if( $resp->is_valid ) 
        {

        } 
        else {
            if( $resp->error == 'incorrect-captcha-sol') {

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is pretty much copy-pasta from the source docs, if I recall - to be honest, I switched to Akismet a while ago...